# Data Fusion CDC with MS SQL version lower than 2016

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cdc, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'd like to use replicate function on Data Fusion with MS SQL server version 2008R2. Is there any workaround to use CDC function with version lower than 2016? Since the document mentioned that available SQL Server 2016 and later.

Expecting to connect with SQL server lower than 2016 version and once connected to the database all the data should not disappear during the way.

Comment: What happens if you try anyway? Can't you simply upgrade the server to be 2016 or newer?

Comment: Thanks @Alejandro for your answer. The database is on customer side. That's why I have to be careful about this. Thanks anyway :)